# UDP packets are dropped when its size is less than 12 byte in a certain PC. how do i figure it out the reason?

Tags: windows, azure, tcp, udp, winsock

i've stuck in a problem that is never heard about before.

i'm making an online game which uses UDP packets in a certain character action. after i developed the udp module, it seems to work fine. though most of our team members have no problem, but a man, who is my boss, told me something is wrong for that module.

i have investigated the problem, and finally i found the fact that... on his PC, if udp packet size is less than 12, the packet is never have been delivered to the other host.

the following is some additional information:

- 1~11 bytes udp packets are dropped, 12 bytes and over 12 bytes packets are OK.
- O/S: Microsoft Windows Vista Business
- NIC: Attansic L1 Gigabit Ethernet 10/100/1000Base-T Controller
- WSASendTo returns TRUE.
- loopback udp packet works fine.

how do you think of this problem? and what do you think... what causes this problem?
what should i do for the next step for the cause?

PS. i don't want to padding which makes length of all the packets up to 12 bytes.

Comment: This might help http://www.isoc.org/inet97/proceedings/F3/F3_1.HTM

Comment: That's about 14 years old. Not likely to be relevant today.

Comment: Did you checked with wireshark if frames are going out?

Comment: Does working PCs ship the same NIC card?

Comment: working PC is not the same NIC card. and i'll try wireshark soon. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to get one of the non-obvious answers in: maybe UDP checksum offload is broken on that card, i.e. the packets are sent, but dropped by the receiver?

You can check for this by looking at the received packets using Wireshark.

Comment: i have checked erroneous packets with wireshark on the both side of end-point. and i have figure out sending UDP packet's checksum is broken. and i've been heard about some of NIC capable of TCP Offload Engine has checksum error before. i turned off TCP Offload option which is initially On. now, it works correctly. thanks y'all!

Comment: and the remaining problem is... make user suffered from this kind of problem know about the solution. or should i make workaround for this? let me think about this...

Answer (score 2):

IF you already checked firewall, antivirus, network firewall, network intrusion. read this

For a UDP packet ethernet_header(14 bytes) + IPv4_header(20 bytes min) + UDP_header (8 bytes) = 42 bytes
Now since its less than the 64 bytes or 60 on linux, network driver will pad the packet with (64-42 = 22 ) zeros to make it 60 bytes before it send out the packet.

that's the minimum length for a UDP packet.
theoretically you can send 0 data bytes packet, but haven't tried it yet.

as for your issue it must be an OS issue . check your network's driver's manual or check with manufacturer. because this isn't suuposed to happen.

REF:http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Course/Section4/8.htm
REF:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Answer (score 2):

Run Wireshark on his PC AND on the destination PC.

Does the log show the udp packet leaving his machine? Does it show it arriving on the destination PC?

What kind of router hardware or switches are between his PC and the destination? Can you remove them and link the two with a cross over cable? (or replace the destination with a laptop and link that to his PC with a cross over cable?)

Have you removed or at least listed all anti virus and firewall products on his machine and anything that installs a Winsock LSP ?

Do ALL 12 byte or less packets get dropped or just some, can you generate packets with random content and see if it's something in the content, rather than just the size, that's causing the issue.

Comment: this answer is also quite helpful for me. i'm appreciate it. but, there is more exact answer. so, i can't help but accept that answer. sorry about that. ;-)

Comment: Fair enough, glad you solved the problem, and I've learned something new :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your problem is with sending *from* his PC: First, run a packet sniffer on the problematic PC to see if it arrives at the NIC. If it makes it there, there may be a problem in the NIC or NIC driver.

Next, check for any running firewall software. Try disabling it and see what happens.

If that doesn't work, clear out any Winsock Layered Service Providers with [`netsh winsock catalog reset`](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/winsock.htm).

If that doesn't work, I'm stumped :)

Finally, you're probably going to find other customers with the same problem; you might want to think about that workaround anyway. Try sending a few small-size UDP packets on connect, and if they consistently fail to go through, enable a padding workaround. For hosts where the probe packets make it through, you don't need to pad them out.

Answer (score 1):

*Pure conjecture*: RTP, which is a very common packet to send on UDP, defines a [12 byte header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol#Packet_header).  I wonder if some layer of network software is assuming that anything smaller is a malformed RTP packet and throwing it away?

Answer (score 0):

This has tripped me up on two IoT related projects where small UDP payloads less than 12 bytes are dropped during the routing from edge device to server and vice versa from certain types of Azure resources.

This article here suggests the route cause on Win and Linux OS hosts is related to the network interface and the issue has been patched. If you have access to the resource network settings (on an Azure Container Instance I dont) you can also amend the NIC properties to disable checksum offload.

Ref
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8610

We found padding UDP packets to 12 bytes in both cases mitigated the issue.

Solutions:

- Patch OS to latest version
- Pad UDP packets to 12 bytes
- Amend NIC properties to disable checksum offload (have not tried this)

Update to add we migrated from using an Azure Container Instance to using a Azure Load Balancer with Windows VM backend pools and running a windows service on the VM. Took a bit more work over a ACI resources to get the deployment pipeline up and running from Azure Dev Ops but works a treat and no longer need to pad the ACKs. VMs are running on Windows Server 2022 data centre edition for ref.